# Kubernetes: AWS EKS: HELM: Promtail Grafana Loki Stack: Storage Optimization

Tags: storage, grafana, amazon-eks, grafana-loki, promtail

For our Test infrastructure in AWS EKS (1.26), I am configuring Promtail Loki and Grafana Stack using Helm Charts where I am finding some difficulties storing logs and need help with retention.

Requirements:

- Storage Type: Gp2
- Max allowable storage: 105 GiB
- Daily log storage: 10-15 GiB (Observed)
- Retention: 8 Days (After that all logs are safe to delete, and need to be deleted)

**I have observed that the "/data" inside **loki-0** pod directory getting filled up very quickly.**

Helm command used to configure the stack:

```
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack --namespace=loki --set grafana.enabled=true,\
prometheus.enabled=true,\
prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=true,\
prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,\
loki.persistence.enabled=true,\
loki.persistence.storageClassName=gp2,\
loki.persistence.size=105Gi,\
config.table_manager.retention_deletes_enabled=true,\
config.table_manager.retention_period=192h,\
loki.limits_config.max_entries_limit=15000,\
compactor.retention_enabled=true,\
compactor.retention_delete_delay=2h,\
compactor.compaction_interval=10m,\
compactor.retention_delete_worker_count=150
```

using the compactor I think I can reduce the size of indexes but I need to know how to free up the storage after 8 days so that the new logs can get in.

I need help regarding the log cleanup after 8 days is there any way to fine-tune the storage usage, is there any misconfiguration or any **--set** flag I am missing or needs to be added?

Comment: I don't see a max_entries_limit entry at https://grafana.com/docs/loki/v2.8.x/configuration/#limits_config , and you didn't set retention_period=8d

Answer (score 0):

After going through a lot of documentation and websites I am using the following setup to ease my deployment:

I have come along with solving various parts of Loki deployment in AWS EKS and am currently using AWS EFS as the main persistance storage class of Loki, using AWS EFS CSI Driver.

Custom helm values for my production environment i.e. **loki-stack-values.yaml**:

```
loki:
  persistence:
    enabled: true
    storageClassName: loki-efs
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
    size: 512Gi
  config:
    limits_config:
      retention_period: 192h
      max_entries_limit_per_query: 50000
      max_cache_freshness_per_query: 15m
      split_queries_by_interval: 30m
    compactor:
      retention_enabled: true
      retention_delete_delay: 30m
      compaction_interval: 30m
    table_manager:
      retention_deletes_enabled: true
      retention_period: 192h
    server:
      grpc_server_max_recv_msg_size: 2147483648
      grpc_server_max_send_msg_size: 2147483648
      http_server_read_timeout: 3600s
      http_server_write_timeout: 3600s
      http_server_idle_timeout: 3600s
    ingester_client:
      remote_timeout: 600s
      grpc_client_config:
        max_recv_msg_size: 2147483648
        max_send_msg_size: 2147483648
    querier:
      engine:
        timeout: 15m
      query_timeout: 15m
    query_range:
      parallelise_shardable_queries: false

grafana:
  enabled: true
  sidecar:
    datasources:
      enabled: true
      maxLines: 50000
  image:
    tag: 8.3.5
  dataproxy:
    timeout: 3600
    logging: true
```

and using that with my helm installation command:

```
$ helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack --namespace=loki --values
loki-stack-values.yaml --set grafana.enabled=true,\
loki.limits_config.retention_period=240,\
loki.limits_config.max_entries_limit_per_query=50000,\
config.table_manager.retention_deletes_enabled=true,\
config.table_manager.retention_period=192h,\
loki.limits_config.max_entries_limit=50000,\
compactor.retention_enabled=true,\
compactor.retention_delete_delay=30m,\
compactor.compaction_interval=30m,\
compactor.retention_delete_worker_count=250
```